# how to fix problem pushing new repository on github

Tags: git, github

I made a new repository on github to display my latest project. I followed the same steps I have in the past with the one exception of that I checked the box to initalized the repository with a readme. When I try to push my project, I get this error

```
$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/dbrewster42/The-Wall.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dbrewster42/The-Wall.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I looked this up and found that it is a common problem, but for people who are updating their repository. I can't find anything about how to fix this problem for a new repository but here are my clumsy attempts

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> master



$ git push -f
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I also tried to change the origin to another repository without the readme but it says "fatal: remote origin already exists."
Any ideas?

Also, these are the steps I follow (the ones that github suggests never worked for me)

1. git init
2. git remote add origin
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "name"
5. git push -u origin master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add a step that pulls the additional changes of a commit (that adds README) before adding your new commit.

1. git init
2. git remote add origin
3. git pull origin master   # Pull new changes before committing
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "name"
6. git push -u origin master